# Best way to avoid capturing a copy of the value in closure

Tags: swift

```
struct Foo {

    var i = 0 { didSet { println("Current i: \(i)") } }

    func delayedPrint() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { _ in
            println("Closure i: \(self.i)")
        })
    }

    mutating func foo() {
        delayedPrint()
        i++
    }
}
```

---

Now the output of

```
var a = Foo()
a.foo()
```

is

```
Current i: 1
Closure i: 0 // I want current value here.
```

I'm wondering what is the best way here to avoid capturing a copy of an ivar.

---

**EDIT 1**

Yes, moving to class was the first and only thing I've thought of but... this one fooled me to think it can be done somehow with struct... Why it works?

```
mutating func foo() {
    delayedPrint()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { _ in
        println("From foo: \(self.i)")
    })
    delayedPrint()
    i++
}
```

Output:

```
Current i: 1
Closure i: 0
From foo: 1
Closure i: 0
```

---

Comment: @matt consider, there are _two_ variants of a copy when a variable will be captured in a closure: copying a struct - which creates a new variable by copying, and copying a class object (a reference) - which just increments the retain count.

Comment: @matt It actually _would_ print the current value of `i`. However, there is also a data race in the code: In order to avoid a data race you need to ensure that variable `i` will be accessed from the main queue only, or choose a dedicated queue or other synchronisation primitives. Otherwise, all bets are off what `println("Closure i: \(self.i)")` will print.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yup, good one. Good question, good answer, good comments.

Comment: Okay, I've done my best with your new puzzle, but I'm mostly guessing. :)

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the puzzle is just about the scope. Somehow I was fooled by this for a while but the fact is, this is struct and it (and its insiders) always will be stored as a value copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering what is the best way here to avoid capturing a copy of an ivar.

That is a misconception. You cannot "capture an ivar" in this way. What you are capturing is `self`! That is exactly why Swift forces you to *say* `self`, so that you understand this fact. Thus, it makes a difference what kind of thing `self` *is*. And that is why it matters whether `self` is a struct or a class. The class instance is mutable in place; the struct instance is not, so a copy is taken at the time of capture and that copy persists independently.

However, you *can* capture a simple Int (i.e. *not* an ivar), and when you do, you get the result you expect:

```
var i = 0
struct Foo {
    func delayedPrint() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            println(i) // 1
        })
    }
    func foo() {
        delayedPrint()
        i++
    }
}
```

---

Now let's talk about the second puzzle that you pose. Here's a rewrite, to clarify what the puzzle is:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
struct Foo {
    var i = 0
    mutating func foo() {
        delay(0.5) {
            println("From foo: \(self.i)") // 1
        }
        bar(2)
        i++
    }
    func bar(d:Double) {
        delay(d) {
            println("from bar: \(self.i)") // 0
        }
    }
}
```

I'll test it like this:

```
var a = Foo()
a.foo()
a.bar(1)
```

The console shows:

```
From foo: 1 [after half a second]
from bar: 1 [after 1 second]
from bar: 0 [after 2 seconds]
```

So how can `bar` be called the second time 1 second *later*, yet show a value of `self.i` that is *earlier*? And why does `foo` behave differently?

The answer has to do with the fact that everything is happening inside functions - including the definitions of the anonymous functions. The code has to *run* at some point. Until then, the anonymous function is not defined.

1. First let's consider `a.bar(1)`. This causes bar to run and to define the anonymous function which will capture `self`. But this happens *after* we have called `foo` and incremented `i`. Thus, the `self` captured at this time has an incremented `i`.
2. Next let's consider what happens when `foo` calls `bar`. It does this *before* incrementing `i`. So now `bar` runs and the anonymous function is defined, and captures `self` with `i` still set at 0. The fact that this result arrives into the console two seconds later is irrelevant; what is important is when the capture took place.
3. Finally we come to the surprising case of the anonymous function inside `foo`. Clearly, the presence of the `i++` inside `foo` make all the difference. Why? Well, when `foo` runs, it defines an anonymous function that captures `self`. But *this* `self` has *also* been captured inside `foo` itself for the purposes of saying `i++` — which is really `self.i++`. Thus, the change on `self` performed by `i++` is seen by this anonymous function as well, because they are looking at the same `self`.

   In other words, I'm suggesting that you have hit the Mysterious Edge Case of the anonymous function defined within a function that itself mutates `self`. (I don't know if I think this a bug or not; I'm going to submit it to dev forum and see what they think.)

Comment: I don't think that's capturing `i`, is it? `i` is global, so `println(i)` is just using that global variable instead of a captured one.

Comment: @NateCook All environment outside a function referred to inside the function is captured. You can readily see that if you pass the function around (i.e. pass it to another environment where that global doesn't exist) and call it (it still works).

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to use class instead of structure here, because structs are passed by copy and classes by reference

Comment: Please see my EDIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complement @nikolayn perfect answer, here is a sample that can run in the console and that demonstrates how this can be accomplished with a class instead of a struct (and is also free of data races):
(variables are defined explicit so that you can easily debug)

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa


let queue = dispatch_queue_create("sync_queue", nil)!

class Foo {

    var i = 0 { didSet { println("Current i: \(i)") } }
    let sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    func delayedPrint() {
        let i_copy = i
        let t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(t, queue) { _ in
            let _i = self.i
            let _i_copy = i_copy
            println("Closure i: \(_i)")
            println("Closure i_copy: \(_i_copy)")
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(self.sem)
        }
    }

    func foo() {
        delayedPrint()
        dispatch_async(queue) {
            self.i++
        }
    }

    func wait() {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
}

var a = Foo()
a.foo()
a.wait()
```